# Sending Email to multiple recipients using VBA.array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, outlook, spreadsheet

I have the recipients listed in a VBA.array. The use for this is because it is matching the nth position of the other arrays. I am experiencing a problem when trying to reference two cells that are in different locations of the sheet for the recipient email address. Let's say for example on the second range I want the recipients to be email addresses listed in both A1 and E63 and they should be included on the same message not sent separate emails.

```
Option Explicit

Private WorksheetNames As Variant
Private ValueRanges As Variant
Private OldValues As Variant

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    WorksheetNames = VBA.Array("Info", "Info")
    ValueRanges = VBA.Array("E16:E20", "E22:E25")
    OldValues = GetValues
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    ComposeAndSendMails
End Sub

Private Sub ComposeAndSendMails()
    
    Const COPY_COLUMNS As String = "A:E"
    Const ROW_DELIMITER As String = vbLf
    Const COL_DELIMITER As String = " - "
    Dim cIndices(): cIndices = VBA.Array(1, 2, 3, 5) ' skip column 'D'
    Dim Recipients(): Recipients = VBA.Array("E61", "E63")
    
    Dim rLen As Long: rLen = Len(ROW_DELIMITER)
    Dim cLen As Long: cLen = Len(COL_DELIMITER)
    Dim cUpper As Long: cUpper = UBound(cIndices)
    
    Dim BaseName As String:
    With ThisWorkbook
        BaseName = Left(.Name, InStrRev(.Name, ".") - 1)
    End With
    
    Dim NewValues(): NewValues = GetValues
    If IsEmpty(GetValues) Then Exit Sub ' covered in 'GetValues'
    
    Dim bData(), n As Long, r As Long, c As Long, eCount As Long
    Dim Body As String, Recipient As String
    
    For n = 0 To UBound(NewValues)
        If IsColumnDifferent(OldValues(n), NewValues(n)) Then
            With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(WorksheetNames(n))
                bData = .Range(ValueRanges(n)).EntireRow _
                    .Columns(COPY_COLUMNS).Value
                Recipient = CStr(.Range(Recipients(n)).Value)
            End With
            For r = 1 To UBound(bData, 1)
                For c = 0 To cUpper
                    Body = Body & bData(r, cIndices(c)) & COL_DELIMITER
                Next c
                Body = Left(Body, Len(Body) - cLen)
                Body = Body & ROW_DELIMITER
            Next r
            Body = Left(Body, Len(Body) - rLen)
            SendMailSimple BaseName, Recipient, Body
            eCount = eCount + 1
            Body = ""
        End If
    Next n

    If eCount > 0 Then
        OldValues = NewValues
    End If
    
    MsgBox IIf(eCount = 0, "No", eCount) & " message" _
        & IIf(eCount = 1, "", "s") & " sent.", _
            IIf(eCount = 0, vbExclamation, vbInformation)

End Sub

Private Function GetValues() As Variant
    
    If IsEmpty(WorksheetNames) Then
        MsgBox "The initial information got lost!", vbExclamation
        Exit Function
    End If
 
    Dim UB As Long: UB = UBound(WorksheetNames)
    Dim Jag(): ReDim Jag(0 To UB)
    
    Dim n As Long
 
    For n = 0 To UB
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(WorksheetNames(n)).Range(ValueRanges(n))
            Jag(n) = .Value
        End With
    Next n
        
    GetValues = Jag
 
End Function

Function IsColumnDifferent( _
    ByVal OldData As Variant, _
    ByVal NewData As Variant, _
    Optional ByVal ColumnIndex As Long = 1) _
As Boolean
    Dim r As Long
    For r = LBound(OldData, 1) To UBound(OldData, 1)
        If CStr(OldData(r, ColumnIndex)) <> CStr(NewData(r, ColumnIndex)) Then
            IsColumnDifferent = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next r
End Function

Sub SendMailSimple( _
         ByVal Subject As String, _
         ByVal Recipient As String, _
         ByVal Body As String)
    With CreateObject("Outlook.Application").CreateItem(0)
        .Subject = Subject
        .To = Recipient
        .Body = Body
        .Send
    End With
End Sub
```

I received help on this code from user VBasic, but he hasn't responded to my follow up question for a few days, so I am hoping to receive more help in this thread.

Comment: Why not engage with your previous question on this?  There are questions an an proposed answer there...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76708473/how-to-use-a-vba-array-to-reference-non-sequential-cells

Comment: It to, did not provide the appropriate solution. I am hoping a restructured question with an updated piece of coding will help spark new answers and a working solution

Comment: When a post doesn't give the answer you hope for, it's a good idea to address any questions/comments there before creating a new question.  If people spend time trying to help you, don't just ignore them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add A1 into array

```vb
    Recipients = VBA.Array("E61", "A1,E63")
```

and edit code

```vb
    'Recipient = CStr(.Range(Recipients(n)).Value)
    Dim cel As Range
    Recipient = ""
    For Each cel In .Range(Recipients(n))
       Recipient = Recipient & ";" & CStr(cel)
    Next
    Recipient = Mid(Recipient, 2)
```

Comment: c is already defined As Long a few lines above. 


Dim bData(), n As Long, r As Long, c As Long, eCount As Long

Comment: you are awesome. Worked like a charm. Can I ask why the original wouldn't work? Is it the absence of the ";"?

Comment: @customsheets If you have a non-contiguous range like "A1,E63" you have to iterate each cell in that range to build a single string of their values. ";" is the appropriate delimiter for email recipients. The value of `Range("A1,E63")` would just be the first cell A1.